# Convergence of the series $\sum_n\sqrt{a_n\cdot a_{n+1}}$ given that $\sum_na_n$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{a_n\cdot a_{n+1}}$ converges given that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges when $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$   is a non negative sequence. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the inequality $\sqrt{xy}\leq \frac{x+y}{2}$ for $x,y\geq 0$ to compare $\sum\sqrt{a_na_{n+1}}$ to $\sum_n a_n$ and $\sum_{n}a_{n+1}$.

Comment: Minor error: that should be $ xy \leq \frac {x^2+y^2}{2}$. But otherwise a good answer.

Comment: Good catch, thanks